# Event for Selected Feature when Editing?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Are there Events in the ArcGIS JavaScript API that I can use to get the selected features being used by the attribute inspector and when features are added to the map?

I am using the editor widget in combination with the Attribute Inspector. I have also created a Template picker and used that with the editor widget.

In my application, I am editing points, lines, and polygons from a Feature Server using the On Demand Mode. I have seen examples that show selected features using the On Selection mode, but was not pleased with having to add both the map server and the featureServer layers so I am trying to find another way.

I would like to be able to start a function that draws a graphic for the point features when they are selected and displayed in the attribute inspector, as well as when the features are first completed but don't know which event is firing.

I appreciate any assitance.

Thanks,

Mele

Answer (score 3):

```
dojo.connect( layername, "onEditsComplete", function(a, u, d) { alert('edited'); });
```

This will alert you to the add, update, or delete

hope this helps...